# Does the electrification in clouds influence their growth or movement?

Tags: electrostatics, meteorology

The electricity in clouds is often correlated with cloud microphysics and vertical winds, and we have only one way interaction of clouds to form electricity within them. Does the induced electric field further respond to the cloud growth or its motion? i.e. is it possible to have a two way interaction of cloud hydrometeors and electric charges?